# how to delete redis from my ubuntu-16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

When I run `sudo systemctl status redis` i get this

```
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-05-11 03:43:43 
WEST; 
31min ago
Main PID: 1553 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 11 03:43:42 fevrok systemd[1]: redis.service: Control process exited, 
code=exited status=203
May 11 03:43:42 fevrok systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 11 03:43:42 fevrok systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 11 03:43:43 fevrok systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 11 03:43:43 fevrok systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
May 11 03:43:43 fevrok systemd[1]: redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 11 03:43:43 fevrok systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

and when I run `sudo systemctl status redis-server` i get this

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-05-11 03:25:48 WEST; 49min ago
 Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
       man:redis-server(1)
Main PID: 1121 (redis-server)
CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
       └─1121 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

May 11 03:25:48 fevrok systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
May 11 03:25:48 fevrok run-parts[1116]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d/00_example
May 11 03:25:48 fevrok run-parts[1122]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.post-up.d/00_example
May 11 03:25:48 fevrok systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

it looks like I'm having 2 redis services in my machine so how can i remove the first one because it's old and not working when I try to start it, maybe because i tried to delete it long time ago so i think i did it worng so the question is: how i can delete this service : `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**If you used apt-get when installing**

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove redis-server
```

**If you used makefile when installing**

[How to uninstall Redis server from Ubuntu](http://grainier.net/how-to-uninstall-redis-server-from-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge redis
```

If it's not work ,you can try to find the redis files and remove it,mostly,the redis is at /usr/bin/redis

Comment: I didn't install it from `apt-get` this is how I install it using this article from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) using makefile